# MKMapview memory problem.Zooming-scrolling

Tags: iphone, memory, ipad, mkmapview

I am developing a mapview application.When i look to instruments i see no leak in my application which is good.But my problem is whenever user scrolls,zooms in,zooms out the map,default mapview starts to allocate memories of MBs.When my application reaches about 25-30 mb then map releases some data which is about 5-6 mb s.But about 25mb of memory is still allocated.After a while my applications starts to throw memory warning.

The reason for it is that mapview stores the visited places in its memory and so in my application
I want to know if there is a way to limit memory allocation of mapview or make it release some data before 25mb-30mb.

Thanks for your support.I would really be preciated.

Comment: I have the exact same issue.  Did you figure anything out?